# Batch file to copy/rename directory recursively and find/replace file contents

Tags: windows, batch-file

A windows batch file is needed to make a copy of a directory tree and rename occurrences of a given old_name to a given new_name, please see example below.
I looked at `robocopy` and `xcopy` for no avail

```
String old = "old_name";
String new = "new_name";

current directory:
C:\old_name
C:\old_name\table
C:\old_name\garage\old_name\chair\a.file (contains text I am OLD_NAME)
C:\old_name\garage\old_name\b.file (contains text I am old_name)

desired outcome:
C:\new_name
C:\new_name\table
C:\new_name\garage\new_name\chair\a.file (contains text I am NEW_NAME)
C:\new_name\garage\new_name\b.file (contains text I am new_name)
```

edit:
showing one node in the path which is not being changed to the new name.

old_name=twintyone

new_name=one

C:\Users\fredJ\AndroidStudioProjects\one\app\src\main\java\mx\com\businessman\twintyone

Comment: This is a task request, not a question! please share what you have tried so far and, if stuck at a certain point, describe exactly what is the problem you are facing...

Comment: I wrote a java code which loops over all files names, subString and replaceString is used alot, then open each file and read lines and replace found strings with desired. it is a task in java and I was hoping that a Xcopy might have a nifty magic to do it instead. :)

Comment: Nah, the built-in utilities can't do it. You'll have to write the code that would either rename files after the copying is done or do a file-by-file processing. Or maybe there's some utility that can do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any single utility that will do everything you want, but if you deploy my [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) and [JREN.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081) utilities, then a simple batch script can easily and efficiently accomplish your goal.

Both JREPL.BAT and JREN.BAT are hybrid JScript/batch scripts that run natively on any Windows machine from XP onward - no executables need to be copied or installed.

The batch script has 3 simple steps:

1. Use XCOPY to copy your directory tree
2. Use JREN.BAT to appropriately rename OLD_NAME folders to NEW_NAME
3. Use FINDSTR to identify files that contain OLD_NAME, iterate the result with FOR /F, and edit each found file with JREPL.BAT

I also add a few ECHO statements so you can follow the progress

*Note - the following is untested. If there is a bug, there should be a simple fix - the basic design is sound*

```
@echo off
set "old=OLD_NAME"
set "new=NEW_NAME"
xcopy "c:\%old%\*" "c:\%new%" /i /s
call jren "^.+" "%new%" /d /s /p "c:\%new%" /fm "%old%"
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('findstr /mspc:"%old%" "c:\%new%\*"') do (
  echo Editing "%%F"
  call jrepl "%old%" "%new" /l /f "%%F" /o -
)
echo(
echo Done!
```

Comment: +1 for the design. things to do is: renaming any directory in the paths not just the root directory, renaming of the string inside each file is buggy.

Comment: @FredJ. - The XCOPY creates the root folder with NEW_NAME, and the JREN command already renames all other folders named OLD_NAME in the path, changing them to NEW_NAME. How exactly is the find/replace within each file buggy? Is there some requirement you haven't stated?

Comment: C:\a\b\old_name gets changed to C:\a\b\new_name but C:\a\b\old_name\...\old_name does not get changed to C:\a\b\new_name\...\new_name. \...\ means the name could be anywhere in the path tree

Comment: @FredJ. - It works for me. Is that last node a folder or a file? If you also want to rename files, then it takes another JREN call without the /D option.

Comment: last node is a folder.

Comment: @FredJ. - I cannot reproduce your problem, and all my tests show that the recursive rename of folders works properly. I'd be surprised to find a bug in the utility at this point, but I suppose it is possible. Can you edit your question to show the exact full path that is failing to be renamed, along with the OLD_NAME and NEW_NAME values.